# Display custom price in all the web for a group of customers

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I need to display a custom price for some products to a certain group of customers. I made it, but I only see the custom price in the product view page, and I need to display it in all the web. Now I see the regular price in the product list, and it should also display the custom price.

First I created the custom price attribute `private_price` for the products.

Then I created a module, and listen for the `catalog_product_get_final_price` event:

```
<events>
    <catalog_product_get_final_price>
        <observers>
            <catalog_product_get_final_price_handler>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>privatesales/observer</class>
                <method>modifyFinalPrice</method>
            </catalog_product_get_final_price_handler>
        </observers>
     </catalog_product_get_final_price>
</events>
```

and in the observer:

```
public function modifyFinalPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
    /* If customer is logged in */
    if($isLoggedIn) {
        /* Get the logged in customer's group ID */
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        /* Check if the logged in customer's group ID matches with the ID you are after */
        if ($customerGroupId==2) {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $privatePrice = (double) $product->getPrivatePrice();
            if ($privatePrice>0 && !empty($privatePrice) && !is_null($privatePrice)) {
                $product->setFinalPrice($privatePrice);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm using magento 1.9.2.4

**Update:** I also tried the event `catalog_product_load_after` with same result, price changed in product view, but price remains unchanged in product list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used event for product list **catalog_product_collection_load_after**

> config.xml

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <brolab_erp>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>brolab_erp/observer</class>
            <method>catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter</method>
        </brolab_erp>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

> Observer.php

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getData('collection');
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $item */
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {
        /* your code */
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I tried it before, but I still do not see the `private_price` in the product list. Maybe this custom attribute is not added to the event collection??

Comment: Your will need use additional method for attribute value in items iteration:
`$item->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($item->getId(), 'private_price', Mage::app()->getStore()))`

Comment: Yes! this way it works perfect. But, be careful, because there is an extra closing parenthesis. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I have written without check. Fixed: `$item->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($item->getId(), 'private_price', Mage::app()->getStore())`

Answer (score 0):

*You can set Tier Price of product with respect to customer Group.
So, You can get this feature from Magento Backend by default.
No need to implement extra code.*

try it & let me know.

Comment: This is part of a bigger code, that I simplified. I need to control several things that I can't control with tier prices. So I have to develop it with an observer.